# How to create a calculated column with unique values ​for every field

Tags: sql, hana

I'm currently facing a problem working with a CV on SAP HANA.
*Basically my goal is to create a calculated field on every row, based on the content of another field of the same row.*

More specifically, I have a column of dates with the current format (YYYYMMDD) and I have to automatically create an associated field based on current criterias:

1. the date with the current month and year has to be associated with 0;
2. every month after the current one, has to be, in order, increased by one (example: for 20220930 I have 0, for 20221030 I have 1, for 20221230 I have 3.. for 20231230 I have 15, this until 600);
3. if more than one row has the same date, the calculated field has to be the same, that means that, for example, if more than one row has 20221030, I need to have 1 on all of them).

My first idea was to use a rank node, but the outcome is not as I expected.
Attached, there is a screenshot of a data preview of my attempt (just showing the dates and rank_field columns..).

Any advice is welcome, thanks.

[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t55n.png)